# Reasons for using nuclear weapons?

Tags: nuclear-weapons, nuclear-war

When it comes to nuclear weapons use people are in general extremely simple: a full scale war would see nuclear use. There is rarely any reason given beyond “they have it so they’ll use it”, with some giving a reason like if they feel existentially threatened while often insinuating that any invasion of the home territory would be enough to instantly nuke everything and everyone regardless of how far the invasion might be going or the actual effectiveness of the invasion is determined.

But it cannot be that simple. It is the way America thought nuclear weapons would be used just after WWII up until the Korean and Vietnam war happened and they stepped away from the idea that nukes would be the only warfare from then on.

There are too many reasons not to use nuclear weapons (assuming some rationality of the people handling the nukes!):

- a full scale war will see use of weapons that give you an advantage. You wont be bringing the table knife despite it being capable of being a weapon. If using a nuke causes you to not gain an advantage, say getting nuked back so much you cannot continue the war, then using the nuke will not happen.
- nuclear warfare research has been found to be more effective as a deterrent than actual use.
- nuclear use will also mean domestic problems in most cases. If not directly by the population then through sanctions caused by the rest of the world as any and all bridges are burned until a potential full change in political leadership.
- nuclear weapons use also reduces the effectiveness of your own forces when they have to fight in potential nuclear fallout.
- The risk of nuclear fallout reaching your own country somehow is not insignificant.

So my question is, what clearly defined reasons would there be to actually use nuclear weapons? Taking into account that there is some variation in people.

Edit: hopefully to better clarify the question. I am looking for scenario’s where using nukes would meet the following points:

- it’s advantage is superior to the long-term disadvantages of nuclear use.
- conventional weapons which do not suffer the same consequences as nuclear use are inferior choices in the long run.

And again I am assuming a reasonable rationality. The North Korean “my God who is surrounded by yes-men and has little grasp of the full extend of his actions ordered me to fire a nuke” is not part of a reasonable nuke wielding faction.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141572/discussion-on-question-by-demigan-reasons-for-using-nuclear-weapons).

Answer (score 4):

**Strategic Use by Major Powers**

Building a first 10-kt bomb and a ballistic missile for it may or may not be easier than dropping 10 kt worth of *conventional* explosives on a city. Think of a bomber the size of a B-52 or B-36, times 500 or so, the number of pilots and air crew, bases, maintenance, ... compared to something like the Manhattan Project.

Building a hundred 100-kt bombs, and a hundred [IRBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate-range_ballistic_missile) or bombers, is almost certainly cheaper than a hundred "[thousand bomber raids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thousand-bomber_raids)." So nukes are the way to go when a major industrial power wants to smash the industrial potential of another major industrial power. Note that this is a [countervalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countervalue) targeting strategy.

Once one power as enough ICBMs to smash the cities and industry of another, and then missiles to spare, there will be Cold War style refinements like [counterforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterforce) targeting, launch on warning, MAD, ...

**Tactical** or **Battlefield Use by Major Powers**

The weaker side in a conventional confrontation, like the US and NATO in the early Cold War (vs. the Warsaw Pact), or North Korea or Russia today (vs. NATO and not just Ukraine), may threaten to 'go nuclear' to overcome a possible conventional defeat. There was a widely stated assumption that such 'theater nuclear use' would with high likelihood lead to global nuclear war. Of course saying so was part of public signalling for deterrence purposes.

**Use by Minor Powers against Major Powers**

This is actually a bit like MAD, except that it isn't mutual destruction. The minor power threatens to inflict *unacceptable damage* on the major power if the major power tries to *destroy* the minor power. It would be unlikely that a country like North Korea could build an air force to get a thousand intercontinental bombers through to the US. It may or may not be able to get an ICBM through. (Who knows exactly how well the missile defenses would perform outside exercises?)

Two variants: Perhaps the minor power just wants to be left alone, free to build socialism their own style or to suppress women and religious minorities their own style, and they need the threat of doing just a little bit of nuclear damage to the superpower to be left alone. Or they want to use the 'nuclear umbrella' to engage in a regional power move, and it would take rather more to make the superpower go away. Either way, the necessary reputation that they would push the button if push came to shove might cause others to want to disarm them.

That threat has to be credible. We cannot know if North Korea or Russia would really push the button, but can we exclude it? Regarding the personality to do it, think of someone who *genuinely* believes that the country/people would be worthless without the current regime (read about the last months of the Nazi leadership), or someone who is convinced that defeat means *personal* death, and who does not care about the people (like Saddam Hussein, probably).

A special case might be Israel and South Africa. South Africa wanted nuclear weapons to coerce the West to help them in conventional conflict. Israel may have elements of that, too.

**Use by Regional Powers against Regional Powers**

A bit like major powers against each other, but on a smaller scale and under the shadow of the superpowers. Pakistan and India cannot destroy the world. They can do serious damage to each other.

Other points:

- You may be overestimating fallout. Look who lives in Hiroshima and Nagasaki today.
- Sanctions only matter if there is something left to sanction. What can the US do to Iran to tighten the screw, other than going to war?
- Regarding deterrence by research, [nuclear latency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_latency) aka 'virtual arsenals' might prompt a faster attack. If one state is sure that another state is one month from having a bomb, will it attack now?

Comment: Well researched but it does not deal with the potential consequences as much. A thousand conventional attacks may be superior to several nuclear one’s. Even Russia, which as you noted in the sources does countervalue attacks, does not use nukes for this in Ukraine or Syria despite it likely having won them the war if they had. As the international costs and potential nuking they will receive in the future are too risky. Just imagine being a nuclear capable country and Russia threatens you somehow after it used nukes, you are better off launching first then… right?

Comment: @Demigan, according to the internationally accepted borders, it is Russia occupying parts of Ukraine. See my note of tactical nukes as the last-ditch tool of the weaker power to prevent getting overrun.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can have much lower costs to fire and make artillery, since you can make very energy dense shells. It's much more easy to stop human wave attacks by a high tech power. This was touted as a valuable use in the Korean war.
2. You can break tunnels and bunkers underground a lot more easily with the massive firepower.
3. You can destroy industrial or military areas very easily. It's very hard to stop a large number of nuclear weapons.

They have some major advantages over conventional firepower.

Comment: The lower cost of a nuclear artillery/bunkerbusting/stragetic bombing would be offset by your opponent using them and the loss of standing in the international community. That is the problem I am trying to figure out. People say “you have nukes so you’ll use them in a full scale war” but the consequences for their use are massive. Just look at Russia: fully capable of using nukes against Syria and Ukraine, but has yet to use them even though some of the requirements of their use have been met. Something has prevented their use, so what would be needed to start using them?

Answer (score 2):

Since the main reasons to not use nuclear weapons are the consequences that would result from other nations' reactions, and those consequences are so great in magnitude that no reasonable potential gain from using nukes could ever exceed them, using nuclear weapons only makes sense if you can mitigate those consequences in some way.

- **Nothing left to lose.** If you are losing a war, and you expect the outcome of defeat to be destruction of your nation, or for some people just their own personal death, then whatever consequences you get for using nukes are still probably better than the alternative of accepting defeat.
- **Global agreement that it's justified.** Many nuclear armed nations have longstanding publicly announced strategic policies that they will use their nukes in response to an enemy using nuclear weapons first, and most nations accept such policies as reasonable. If such a policy is triggered, following through on it and using your nukes against the offending nation will provoke little or no sanctions or reprisals.
- **Calling a perceived bluff.** If you believe that the nations threatening you with potential sanctions and/or nuclear reprisals lack the conviction and commitment to follow through on their threats, possibly because your plan is on a small enough scale that the threatened response might not be clearly justified, then if you are correct the consequences will actually be minor.
- **Strong defense system.** The threat of nuclear weapons is so effective as a deterrent in large part because there is no known way to reliably defend against them. If you have developed a defense system that you are confident will successfully protect you from enemy nukes, then the most severe part of the consequences for using nuclear weapons is negated.

Answer (score 0):

1: taking out numerically superior Enemy Assets:

Examples include if your enemy has a US Style carrier strike force - a single nuclear device delivered either by torpedo or by a Tomahawk type system could destroy completely or severely restrict their combat effectiveness.

Or Soviet era massed Tank battalions.

2: Shock and Awe:

Okay, so since Hiroshima, this is debatable, but if your opponent doesn't know you are Nuclear armed, a nuclear explosion is a really good way to get them to reconsider.

3: Terror:

Not a nice option, but public outrage, especially for Western powers is often more potent than any weapon. Using a Nuke to illicit such a response could be a viable option.

4: death or Glory:

If you are in a war where loosing means total annihilation for your country/group/way of life - then using nuclear weapons becomes much more logical: We are dead already, so why does it matter?

Comment: Aside from #4 all of these are almost guaranteed to get you a retaliatory strike or some counter that is going to be as costly if not costlier. I’m trying to figure out what kind of nuclear use you would do and be better off than conventional weapons that do not have as much drawbacks. Also even in #4 the option of a small tactical nuke to show willingness to use them and then go back to the negotiating table would be a superior choice as you invoke a MAD style tactic.

Comment: Soviet tanks were *somewhat* designed to operate under nuclear conditions, and would they have massed *WWII-*Soviet-style?

Comment: @Demigan - If you'd posed this question 20 or even 10 years ago, I would have agreed that using a Nuke in *any* capacity would have been an automatic Death Sentence, Today and in the near future? I'm not so sure. I suspect taking out a Carrier Task force, in the context of a conventional war, could be done without a retaliatory strike (e.g. if it was in the middle of the Ocean).

Comment: @TheDemonLord There are more ways to punish a nuclear attack. Although an attack on a carrier may be the only exception where using nukes can be more advantageous for you than using alternatives. But it does not justify the ideology of “if you have nukes, you’ll use it”. Even against carrier groups its likely some line would need to be crossed before using nukes, like “we ran out of conventional anti-ship missiles”.

Answer (score -2):

### Missiles

Missiles need fuel, energy dense fuel. What fuel is more energy dense than nuclear?

### Satellites

Satellites also need energy dense fuel. Satellites can be used as weapons themselves. For example by firing highly intense energy waves.

### Aircraft Carriers and Submarines

You cannot really have world class aircraft carriers and submarines, stuff that can actually make a difference in a war against real power players, without having them utilize nuclear fuel.

Comment: Nuclear weapons, not nuclear fuel options. And having non-nuclear powered subs and aircraft carriers is absolutely possible in peer-to-peer combat. In fact aside from nuclear missile submarines the use of Diesel Subs has great advantages. A nuclear engine will always need pumps to keep the powerplant cool, a diesel sub going on batteries is more silent and capable than a nuclear submarine.

Comment: Swords, maces and clubs are weapons, right? They hit the enemy. Is a rifle a weapon? Everybody will say it is. How many times it itself hit the enemy? Its a weapon because it send bullets and the bullets hit the enemy. You cannot have bullets flying without likes of rifles etc. Is a train carrying soldiers to battlefield who then later charge manually on enemy with bayonets a weapon? If rifle is then train is too. Is propaganda a weapon? There will be no rifles at battlefield and no trains carrying soldiers if there wasn't propaganda before to have public opinion in favour of war.

Comment: Is an aircraft carrier a weapon? Everybody will say it is. Do you smash it on enemy vessels? No. Do you use it to fire cannons on enemy vehicles? Rarely. How is it a weapon then? It is because it carry airplanes who do the firing on enemy vessels and ports. Neither the airplanes nor the aircraft carriers hit the enemy. The bombs and bullets do. Yet you cannot have those bombs and bullets hitting enemy without the airplanes, and you cannot have those airplanes there without  the aircraft carrier. Similarly, you cannot have that aircraft there without nuclear fuel. Logistics alone will prevent.

Comment: by your logic diesel powered aircraft&subs are diesel weapons. Which we dont classify as such. If you read the question I am not looking for some fancy way to reclassify what a nuclear weapon is, but at what point having nuclear weapons results in their usage. Again, weapons, not warships that carry weapon systems. Because an aircraft carrier is a warship, not a weapon itself. Also guns are now people powered weapons! Because someone carries it!

Comment: An aircraft carrier is not a weapon? By your definition even a rifle is not a weapon unless used as a club. Apparently you dont know difference between ammunition and weapon. A hydrogen bomb is ammunition, not weapon, sir, because its consumed when used.

Comment: a warship is not the weapon, it carries weapon systems. Although its still a mute point, as you utilize it as an engine, not a weapon.

Comment: @Demigan By that definition a strategic nuclear bomber plane thats whole job is to fire a nuclear missile that burst into multiple nuclear "vehicles" is not a weapon. Where will you stop? How is rifle a weapon? Its just an engine you know that fire bullets. An airplane is just an engine in its entirety whose sole purpose is to fire bombs and bullets at target.